# lombok @ToString for field marked as @NonNull String @NonNull [] name

Tags: java, tostring, lombok

Lombok's @ToString annotation generates bad String for field:

```java
private @NonNull String @NonNull [] answers;
```

Class code:

```java
@Getter
@Builder
@ToString
public class SongEntryDto extends EntityDto {
    @ToString.Exclude
    private byte @NonNull [] data;
    private @NonNull String @NonNull [] answers;
}
```

Output:

```
SongEntryDto(answers=[Ljava.lang.String;@68f7aae2)
```

Comment: The lombok issue tracker is available via `https://www.projectlombok.org/` - make sure to mention the bug, specifically, is that lombok's toString fails to recognize it needs to invoke `Arrays.toString` here due to the nonnull annotations.